# Create connection to SQL from VB.net application

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm looking in to learning some coding and have a small project in mind to begin with,

To begin if anyone could point me in the direction of some good VB.net resources I would be very appreciative,

On a more specific note, I have a few particular questions:

I have a form with several text boxes, how would I go about using this form to establish a connection to an SQL database whereby the boxes on the form are used for (1, servername\instance. 2, database name. 3, sql login. 4,sql password) triggered by pressing the 'connect' button

I also have a form with a single text box, I would like to be able to query a specific table for records where based on primary key = contents of text box. On the form, I'd like to have other text boxes which link to columns on the table and return the value of the associated record.

As a development of the above, I would like to then have a button that writes any changes to the information back on to the record in SQL.

If anyone is able to offer any advise or insight on how I would begin going about this, that would be great.

I would much rather sources of how to learn to do the above that code if possible.

Comment: My advice is to read [Ask], the [Faq] and take the [Tour].  You are asking for a tutorial which is not what this site is about.  There are many thousands of answers here dealing with DBs help yourself.

Comment: You should tell us _which_ database you are using. "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases. So all RDBMS are "SQL databases". How you connect to the database server (you don't "connect to SQL") depends a lot on the DBMS you are using.

Comment: If you're just trying to learn a little coding, maybe jumping into databases and learning two languages at once isn't the best approach...but if you really want to try that, then I would suggest writing your program out in pseudocode, think about what you need to do and outline it in small simple steps. Then search this site (or google) for information on how to do each of those small steps. If you get stuck along the way then post your code and your specific problem, there are a lot of people here who would gladly help nudge your code in the right direction

Comment: Hello all, thanks for the comments.

I'm using SQL Express - the database at the moment is just a single table - I would just like to learn how I would write to that database and query it with select statements,

I have a fairly sound knowledge of SQL (not the best but sufficient to insert, update, etc.) so it's mainly just the resources to learn how to direct the program to query the database

Answer (score 0):

Do several thing or post actual code where you are stuck. it sounds like you will ask about how to put values on Database also. honestly want to say, if you research little bit what you want you will definitely get it. first google and then ask.

because you are in learning phase try to gather as much as knowledge rather copy paste code.

HINTS:

1) set your web.config with connection to sql
   see: MSDN document

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400235.aspx

2) Then start coding UI

3) on UI you have different boxes, on each button click you should handle separately

search on:

- How to open SQL Connection on button click
- How to insert new records into a database

and lastly if you came across error then post your issue here.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me, it's nice to know a little about the terms used as that'll give me a better understanding of what to look for